# How to disable nuget package restore with msbuild command line options?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I want to disable NuGet package restore on build and use the individual command for that. Is this possible?

My idea is to use something like this:

```
nuget.exe restore
msbuild.exe /p:NuGetRestorePackages=false
```

Update:

- the package updating can be disabled by `MSBuild.exe ... /p:RestorePackages=false`
- and it looks like `.nuget\nuget.exe restore solution.sln` restores the packages

Comment: You should post your update as an answer rather than an edit to the question.

Answer (score 8):

You can use "MSBuild    **/p:RestorePackages=false**" to disable package restore on build command.

Comment: This worked for me. MSBuild was complaining about the NuGet version so I had to stop MSBuild from trying to restore, and instead ran nuget.exe from the command line before building.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, I suggest making your CLI approach more comprehensive and reliable.

**Short plan**

1. Install Visual Studio Build Tools 2017
2. **Find proper MSBuild**
3. Clean solution
4. Restore packages with nuget **using correct MSBuild**
5. Build solution

---

**Details**

1. Using Build Tools will give you **independence from Visual Studio installation**.

   Download [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15) from [Visual Studio Downloads page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) ([direct link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/3/7/C37763CB-E533-4290-BE34-1DF89C218CFE/vs_BuildTools.exe))

   Command-line arguments documented here: [Use command-line parameters to install Visual Studio 2017](http://Use%20command-line%20parameters%20to%20install%20Visual%20Studio%202017)

   All workloads and components are listed here: [Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 component directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools)
2. Use PowerShell module `VSSetup`. And choose **x86 or x64 MSBuild version**

   Download it or install from here: [Github: Microsoft/Visual Studio Setup PowerShell Module](https://github.com/Microsoft/vssetup.powershell)
3. Run MSBuild with `clean` target
4. Help `nuget.exe` to use proper MSBuild

   `nuget.exe restore -MSBuildPath "C:\..."`
5. Run MSBuild with `build` target (you can add additional required parameters)

---

```
# 1. Find MS Build  

Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\VSSetup\VSSetup.psd1

$msBuildPath = (Get-VSSetupInstance | Select-VSSetupInstance -Version 15.0 -Product Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools).InstallationPath

if ([System.IntPtr]::Size -eq 8)
{
    $global:msbuildPath = Join-Path $msBuildPath 'MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64'
}
else
{
    $global:msbuildPath = Join-Path $msBuildPath 'MSBuild\15.0\Bin'
}

Write-Output "Using MSBuild from $global:msbuildPath"
Write-Output "MSBuild /version"

$msbuild = Join-Path $global:msbuildPath msbuild

& $msbuild /version


# 2. Clean

& $msbuild "$sln_file" /t:Clean /v:q /nologo


# 3. Restore

$nuget = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "\.nuget\nuget.exe"
& $nuget restore -MSBuildPath $global:msbuildPath


# 4. Build

& $msbuild "$sln_file" /t:Build /v:q /nologo
```

> As the result, you will not have any filesystem, PATH or Visual Studio dependencies. And your solution will be reusable on the local machine and a build server.